# Image Processing to detect object that have same color using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, image-processing, colors

I was create empty car space identification system using image processing base on color. However, this system cannot detect the car that have color with parking space. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you already created your program (I'm not sure what "I was create" is supposed to mean)? Does it work with cars that have a different color? What programming language do you use?

Comment: This system is I created for my fyp, and it work when the car's color is not same with parking space base color. I use c# as programming language.

Comment: So you have functioning code. If you want help with that, post the problematic parts, because no one can help you with your code right now.